# Deployed Contract Instance Isn't Detected in Testrpc via MetaMask

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, metamask

When MetaMask tries to access my local testrpc, I'm getting the following error in the browser:

```
contract.js:424 Uncaught (in promise) Error: UnitManager has not been deployed to detected network (1509577107908)
```

Here is my `2_deploy_contracts.js`:

```
var UnitManager = artifacts.require("./UnitManager.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  // deployer.deploy(UnitManager)
  let hash = ''
  deployer
  .then( () => {
    return UnitManager.new()
  })
  .then( instance => {
    instance.setRole(web3.eth.accounts[1], 3, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]})
    return instance
  })  
  // ...
```

I've tried to set the network id explicitly (you can see that in my error) in `truffle.js` and in the command `$ testrpc -i 1509577107908`.

```
module.exports = {
  migrations_directory: "./migrations",
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      // network_id: "*" // Match any network id
      network_id: "1509577107908" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

Notice that I'm not using the standard `deployer.deploy()` command.  I'm using `new()` because I need the `instance` object to run subsequent commands in deployment.

What am I missing here?

Comment: try the same in browser solidity https://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.4.18+commit.9cf6e910.js sometimes it hard to find which one(truffle, Metaask, TestRPC) causes the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use deployer and make an instance that you can call functions on. I wouldn't use new() if it is giving you problems, this seems like it was made for testing not deployment (after reading their documentation)

You can use deployer in this manner:

```
deployer.deploy(ContractA).then(function(){
    var instance = ContractA.at(ContractA.address);
    return instance.doFunction(param1, param2);
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is the method I used today more or less.  This solved the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It strikes me that you have a line commented out:

```
// deployer.deploy(UnitManager)
```

This line seems to deploy the `UnitManager` contract, the same one that the error says is not deployed. Seems like a likely candidate!

Comment: The .new() function deploys - I just don't know where.  The rest of my script runs very specific state-changing functions that pass.  Maybe it's deploying in memory and waiting to send to testrpc until I run .deployer()?